# Haskell: trailing right arrow in a bind operation

Tags: haskell, monads, do-notation

From [haskellwiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/All_About_Monads#Do_notation):
`expr1 >>= \x ->`

I am curious about the right side of the (>>=) operator `\x ->`.
What does it mean?

Nor `\x ->` nor `\x` is recognized by `:type` in *GHCi*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear, the section you're quoting is this:

> The actual translation from do notation to standard monadic operators is roughly that every expression matched to a pattern, `x <- expr1`, becomes
>
> ```hs
> expr1 >>= \x ->
> ```
>
> and every expression without a variable assignment, `expr2` becomes
>
> ```hs
> expr2 >>= \_ ->
> ```
>
> All do blocks must end with a monadic expression, and a let clause is allowed at the beginning of a do block (but let clauses in do blocks do not use the `in` keyword). The definition of `mothersPaternalGrandfather` above would be translated to:
>
> ```hs
> mothersPaternalGrandfather s = mother s >>= \m ->
>                            father m >>= \gf ->
>                            father gf
> ```

So as you can see, the `->` is not actually trailing. If you look at the final example in the quotation above, where `mothersPaternalGrandfather` is defined, you'll see that the `->`s all have a right hand side, which continues on the next line.  The last line in the definition doesn't end with `->`.

As the text on the wiki explains, the `expr1 >>= \x ->` is just "roughly" what happens. You're right that `expr1 >>= \x ->` is not valid syntax.  A more fully parenthesized version of the function definition would look like this:

```hs
mothersPaternalGrandfather s =
  mother s >>= (\m -> father m >>= (\gf -> father gf))
```

Comment: Parenthesized example should' replace the original.

Comment: You mean on the wiki?  I agree, that would probably make it easier to understand.  I'll edit it.

Comment: Yes. I would do "mother s >>= (\m -> father m) >>= (\gf -> father gf)" and then add that parenthesis are not necessary. That would also give a hint about order of operations.

Comment: But that's wrong.  Look more closely at the parentheses in my answer.